# Eclipse shortcut to open run/debug configuration list

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

Is there a shortcut to open the list of saved run/debug configurations as shown below?

[image]

Just to open and select a configuration to run. I really don't like using the mouse everytime to open the dropdown list and select my configuration.

If there isn't a pre-defined shortcut for it, can one be made manually if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>T</kbd> shows you the drop down menu in Run > Run History.

Comment: It's not a one step shortcut. But I guess that's the best there is.